# DotNetNuke (v8.4.1+): LocalResourceFile is not declared

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-8

I am attempting to upgrade a custom in-house developed module from DNN v7.x to DNN v8.x

I updated all the depreciated code, etc... But I am still getting the following error in my ASCX HTML Markup code that I cannot seem to figure out how to fix it...

- 'LocalResourceFile' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to
  it's protection level.
- 'LocalizeString' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its
  protection level.

I made sure there weren't any "web.config" files hiding inside my project directly because I know from previous experience that sometimes that file is generated by Visual Studio and conflicts. I double checked that all my project references are intact. I really don't know what else to try. There is no reason that I can see why I would be getting this error.

Any ideas?

-Ben

Answer (score 0):

LocalResourceFile and LocalizeString are still members of PortalModuleBase, of which your control is probably inheriting. So it's not a matter of depricated code.

Does the ascx only show an error within Visual Studio? Or does it also throw an exception when you run it?

I'd expect the first, in which case Visual Studio probably doesn't find the DotNetNuke.dll file in your build folder. Or it is a different version than you're actually referencing in your project...

Hope this helps

Comment: The error is on both sides, it shows in Visual Studio and it also crashes when it is run on the website. :-(

Comment: The error you get in the browser is the same? Are any other modules giving issues?

Comment: Yes, same error on both the IDE as well as within the browser. This is our first module that we are upgrading to function on DNN 8.x, so I assume that all of our other modules will have the same problem once we begin the upgrade process.